# Handle strictNullChecks when using sort

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting

I wrote a custom function that sorts a map of teams in a local football league by their placement. It looks like this:

```
private sortTeamsByPlacement(teams) {
    return new Map(Array.from(teams).sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.placement === null) {
            return 1;
        } else if (b.placement === null) {
            return -1;
        } else if (a.placement === b.placement) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return (a.placement < b.placement ? -1 : 1);
        }
    }));
}
```

Since I am using `strictNullChecks`, this function yields `Object is possibly 'undefined'.`

What would be the best way to solve this?

The following snippet solved the error, however the solution doesn't "seem" right to me.

```
    return new Map(Array.from(teams).sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.placement === undefined || b.placement === undefined) {
            return 0;
        } else if (a.placement === null) {
            return 1;
        } else if (b.placement === null) {
            return -1;
        } else if (a.placement === b.placement) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return (a.placement < b.placement ? -1 : 1);
        }
    }));
```

Comment: `if( a && a.placement === null )`

Comment: @marekful this doesn't solve it since all conditions might be false and the final "else" would be prone to the strictNullChecks.

Comment: @JohnDoe I think that @marekful was trying to say that `a` or `b` might be undefined - although I would put either `if (!a || a.placement === null)` or add `!a` and `!b` to your undefined placements condition. If that can never happen, your code is fine, however it is up to you to decide how to treat undefined placements - I would possibly treat them the same as nulls, so `if (a.placement === null || a.placement === undefined)`